# Go言語における構造体のメンバへのアクセス（ポインタ）

Tags: go

golang公式Documentにある[Writing Web Applications](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/)の序盤で以下のコードが出てきました.

```
type Page struct {
    Title string
    Body  []byte
}

func (p *Page) save() error {
    filename := p.Title + ".txt"
    return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0600)
}
```

`p.Title`でPage構造体のTitle変数にアクセスしていますが,ここでは
`*p.Title`としないとアクセスできないように見えてしまいます.
何故`p.Title`でアクセスできてしまうのでしょうか.

Comment: 関連情報: [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go言語の仕様です（という回答しかできない気が。。。

仕様は[ここ](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)にあります。

// 本家でも同様の質問をされた方がいるようです

Comment: 構造体の値が渡されても、アドレスが渡されても、p.Titleで一様にアクセスできるのですね
ありがとうございました